# Function pointer which calls a function without specifying parameters

Tags: c++, pointers, function-pointers

I have a function `foo`:

```
void foo(int n) {}
```

and I want to have a pointer that points to the function, but calls it with a specified parameter. So basically, something like this:

```
auto bar =  //init
bar(); //calls foo(2)
```

Comment: This can't be done with a regular function pointer without the use of nonportable features.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `std::bind`:

```
auto bar = std::bind(foo, 2);
```

then you can call it like so:

```
bar();
```

Comment: if I want to make a vector of these how would I do that

Comment: @Julian `bar` would have a return type of `void` and no arguments. You can use `std::function` as a type to the vector: `std::vector<std::function<void(void)>> v;`

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a pointer, c++11 lambdas with no captures are convertible to a function pointer like so

```
#include <iostream>
typedef void(*functype)();

void foo(int n)
{
  std::cout << n;
}

int main()
{
  functype ptr = [](){foo(2);};
  ptr();

  return 0;
}
```